# BitmapFactory.Options inSampleSize crops image

Tags: android

I would like to resize an image and am doing it with the following code:

```
    public Bitmap createWatermark(Bitmap src, String watermark, int x, int y) {
    Log.d("Original Dimensions", src.getWidth() + " x " + src.getHeight());

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 2;
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    src.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, stream);
    byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
    Bitmap result = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byte_arr, 0, byte_arr.length, options).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Log.d("Result Dimensions", result.getWidth() + " x " + result.getHeight());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    paint.setTextSize(40);
    canvas.drawText(watermark, x, y, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawText(watermark, x, y+50, paint);
    return result;
}
```

The log is as follows:

D/Original Dimensions(11180): 1920 x 2560

D/Result Dimensions(11180): 960 x 1280

But the image returned is cropped to 960 x 1280 and not re-sized.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length)
myImageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 960, 1280, false));
```